# Trigger opening of jquery widget dateTimeinput

Tags: jquery

How can I trigger the opening of a datepicker on selection of date from another datepicker?

```
$('#jqxdatetimeinputFromDate').on('change', function (event) {
    //pseudocode
    #jqxdatetimeinputTodate.datepicker.open

});
```

> HTML Code

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="jqxdatetimeinputFromDate"style="padding: 5px">From Date:</label>       
            <div class="form-control" id='jqxdatetimeinputFromdate'></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="jqxdatetimeinputTodate"style="padding: 5px">To Date:</label>
            <div class="form-control" id='jqxdatetimeinputTodate'></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Jquery UI DatePicker ?

I also notice that bootstrap you are using !

Remeber text input will be fine ! Not Div element.

I made an example for you ! [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taiwanhotdog/smeoduq4/)

```js
$( ".dp" ).datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="jqxdatetimeinputFromDate">From Date:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control dp" id="jqxdatetimeinputFromDate" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="jqxdatetimeinputTodate">To Date:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control dp" id="jqxdatetimeinputTodate" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are attempting to answer, I am asking after selecting from date the to date datepicker will open

Comment: 1. Your code is wrong for datepicker control ! How could div element trigger change event ?? 2. Is this you want  ? select from datepicker and set value to other datepicker ?